# Accessing db from stored javascript

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a stored JS fucntion. From the function I would like to search a collection with a `db.bannedwords.find().toArray();` It works when i call the function from db.eval, however if I try to use the function in a $where i get this error error: `{ "$err" : "ReferenceError: db is not defined", "code" : 16722 }` Is because I'm already accessing the DB? and is there a work around?

Comment: Have you already defined `db` somewhere before calling this? Is this in the same scope as where you defined `db`? You might have to post more of your code.

Comment: db has been taken out you cannot get to it since people could not take the hint that this is not how you use MongoDB they actually took it out now

Comment: @Sammaye. Thank you for you comment. So there is no work around right?

Comment: @vch db is a part of mongodb? but i have also tried to do this var var db1 = db.getSiblingDB("myDB"); and the use find on db1, but the result is the same

Comment: Not currently, they have disabled all ability to reach the db object in that envo

Comment: @Sammaye Thank you. Could you post your comment as a answer, then Ill close the question